# Trigger random_id resource recreation on rds instance destroy and recreate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Folks, am trying to find a way with terraform random_id resource to recreate and provide a new random value when the rds instance destroys and recreates due to a change that went in, say the username on rds has changed.

This random value am trying to attach to final_snapshot_identifier of the aws_db_instance resource so that the snapshot should have a unique value to its id everytime it gets created upon rds instance being destroyed.

Current code:

```
resource "random_id" "snap_id" {
  byte_length = 8
}

locals {
  inst_id = "test-rds-inst"  
  inst_snap_id = "${local.inst_id}-snap-${format("%.4s", random_id.snap_id.dec)}"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  .....
  identifier                = local.inst_id  
  final_snapshot_identifier = local.inst_snap_id
  skip_final_snapshot       = false
  username                  = "foo"
  apply_immediately         = true
  .....
}

output "snap_id" {
  value = aws_db_instance.rds.final_snapshot_identifier
}
```

Output after terraform apply:

```
snap_id = "test-rds-inst-snap-5553"
```

**Use case am trying out:**

#1:
Modify value in rds instance to simulate a destroy & recreate:

1. Modify username to "foo-tmp"
2. terraform apply -auto-approve

Output:

```
snap_id = "test-rds-inst-snap-5553"
```

I was expecting the random_id to kick in and output a unique id, but it didn't.

Observation:

- rds instance in deleting state
- snapshot "test-rds-inst-snap-5553" in creating state
- rds instance recreated and in available state
- snapshot "test-rds-inst-snap-5553" in available state

#2:
Modify value again in rds instance to simulate a destroy & recreate:

1. Modify username to "foo-new"
2. terraform apply -auto-approve

Kind of expected below error, coz snap id didn't get a new value in prior attempt, but tired anyways..

Observation:

```
**Error:** error deleting DB Instance (test-rds-inst): DBSnapshotAlreadyExists: Cannot create the snapshot because a snapshot with the identifier test-rds-inst-snap-5553 already exists.
```

Am aware of the `keepers{}` map for `random_id` resource, but not sure on what from the `rds_instance` that I need to put in the map so that the random_id resource will be recreated and it ends up providing a new unique value to the snap_id suffix.

Also I feel using any attribute of rds instance in the `random_id` keepers, might cause a circular dependency issue. I may be wrong but haven't tried it though.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `taint` on the `random_id` resource, as per the documentation [1]:

> To force a random result to be replaced, the `taint` command can be used to produce a new result on the next run.

Alternatively, looking at the example from the documentation, you could do something like:

```
resource "random_id" "snap_id" {
  byte_length = 8

  keepers {
    snapshot_id = var.snapshot_id
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  .....
  identifier                = local.inst_id  
  final_snapshot_identifier = random_id.snap_id.keepers.snapshot_id
  skip_final_snapshot       = false
  username                  = "foo"
  apply_immediately         = true
  .....
}
```

This means that until the value of the variable `snapshot_id` changes, the `random_id` will generate the same result. Not sure if that would work with `locals`, but you could try replacing `var.snapshot_id` with `local.inst_snap_id`. If that works, you could then name the snapshot using built-in functions like `formatdate` [2] and `timestamp` [3] to create a snapshot id which will be tied to the time when you were running apply, something like:

```
locals {
  inst_id = "test-rds-inst"
  snap_time = formatdate("YYYYMMDD", timestamp())
  inst_snap_id = "${local.inst_id}-snap-${format("%.4s", random_id.snap_id.dec)}-${local.snap_time}"
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs#resource-keepers

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/formatdate

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/timestamp

Comment: Apparently can't use local.inst_snap_id, will lead in to cycle issue. Adding the timestamp to the identifier will output a change in state whenever the timestamp changes.